# Srimad Bhagavatham - Version without commentaries

Tags: bhagavata-purana, chaitanya-bhagavata

I would like to request the following as many may be looking for this sort of avenue. For people who have read and re-read Bhghavatham using Bhakthavedantha Prabhpada version, going through the purports and translations are not necessary. This means, for anytime, anywhere quick reading, it would be best if there is an English version that can just put down only the English translation of every sloka. I had seen a version like this by ABC as a HTML version. But a PDF would be better Is there any version (PDF file) without commentaries and purports? Please let us know. Thanks.

Comment: the problem with your request is that there are 1) different recensions of the Gita. 2) Sanskrit is not written as English is with sentences, but rather 'stops'. 3) Sanskrit is often open to interpretation as to the exact meaning or translation.  There is a pocket size English version based on the oldest recension of the GIta with no commentaries, translation by Swami Nikhilananda. Available from Advaita Ashram in India and Vedanta Press in the West.

Comment: Do you want Prabhupada's translation only or any other translation is also fine?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Unless I misunderstand, the OP was asking about Srimad Bhagavatam, and your answer appears to be about Srimad Bhagavad Gita?